# VBA - If Previous Day is a Bank Holiday, Open File From Previous Working Day

Tags: excel, weekday, vba

I am struggling with working this one out. Basically, what I currently have is code to open the previous working days file.

```
x = Weekday(Date, vbSunday)
    Select Case x
        Case 1
            x = 2
        Case 2
            x = 3
        Case Else
            x = 1

    End Select

    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "filepath" & Format(Date - x, "yymmdd") & " - filename.xlsx"
```

Obviously the above doesn't take into consideration Bank/Public Holidays. How can I build this into my code, so for example:

Thursday 29/03/2018 - Working day

Friday 30/03/2018 - Good Friday (Bank Holiday)

Monday 02/04/2018 - Easter Monday (Bank Holiday)

Tuesday 03/04/2018 - Working day

When I come in on Tuesday and run my macro I want it to pick up the last working days file and use that (Thursday 29/03). With my current code that wouldn't be picked up and it would be looking for Mondays file (which obviously doesn't exist).

I hope that makes sense !

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last previous workday with the

- [WorksheetFunction.WorkDay Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-workday-method-excel) or
- [WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-workday_intl-method-excel)
  (which lets you choose which days in a week are the weekend)

So get the last previous workday with …

```
Dim LastPreviousWorkday As Date
LastPreviousWorkday = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date(), -1)
```

And eg. output it formatted

```
Format$(LastPreviousWorkday, "yymmdd")
```

You can tell the `WorkDay` function which dates (additionally to weekends)  should be considered as holidays, eg by giving an array or range as third argument.

```
Dim BankHolidays As Variant
BankHolidays = Array(#3/26/2018#, #3/23/2018#) 'array of bank holidays, or a range in a 
                                               'sheet where the dates of bank holidays
                                               'are saved in.

Dim LastPreviousWorkday As Date
LastPreviousWorkday = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1, BankHolidays)
```

or if you want to use a worksheet with holiday dates

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1, Worksheets("MyHolidays").Range("A:A"))
 'considers all dates in column A of sheet MyHolidays as non-workdays
```

Comment: Will take into consideration Bank Holidays?

Comment: @Jason no Excel doesn't know bank holidays. This function considers federal holidays only. But you can add a list of dates that have to be considered as bank holidays (see my edit).

Comment: That's great @Pᴇʜ!
I think I might create a worksheet with the dates, I assume in the array I will just have to replace the physical dates with the cell range?

Comment: You should be able to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Date, -1, Worksheets("MyHolidays").Range("A:A"))` if you added all dates considered to be holidays in column A of sheet `MyHolidays`. But I think I was wrong with federal holidays, so you will need to add all dates you want to be considered as non-workday (except weekends which are automatically considered non-workdays).

Comment: Thank you @Pᴇʜ - you have been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an over the top answer - the bulk of the code is figuring out which days are bank holidays (in the UK) and gets the main ones (royal weddings/deaths withstanding).

You'll also need a worksheet in your file called `Holidays` and it will create a named range called "BankHolidays".

Then it just uses the `Workday` formula that @Peh used in his answer.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim CurrentWorkDay As Date
    Dim LastWorkDay As Date

    Dim wrkBk_To_Open As Workbook

    'Day after Easter Monday.
    CurrentWorkDay = DateSerial(2018, 4, 3)

    'CHANGE YEAR AS REQUIRED - all other procedures are because of this.
    DisplayBankHolidays 2018

    'THIS IS THE ONLY IMPORTANT LINE OF CODE - THE ONE THAT CALCULATES THE LAST WORK DAY.
    LastWorkDay = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(CurrentWorkDay, -1, Range("BankHolidays"))

    MsgBox Format(LastWorkDay, "ddd dd mmm yy"), vbOKOnly

    'Set wrkBk_To_Open = Workbooks.Open("filepath\" & Format(LastWorkDay, "yymmdd") & " - filename.xlsx")
    'msgbox wrkbk_to_open.name & vbcr & "contains " & wrkbk_to_open.sheets.count & " sheets."

End Sub

Public Sub DisplayBankHolidays(lYear As Long)

    Dim BH As Collection
    Dim vBH As Variant
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim HolidaySheet As Worksheet


    Set BH = New Collection

    Set HolidaySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Holidays")

    Set BH = BankHolidays(lYear)
    lRow = HolidaySheet.Cells(HolidaySheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For Each vBH In BH
        Sheet1.Cells(lRow, 1) = vBH
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next vBH

    With HolidaySheet
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, 1)).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo
        AllocateNamedRange ThisWorkbook, "BankHolidays", "='" & HolidaySheet.Name & "'!" & .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Address, "A1"
    End With

End Sub

'This could be improved - just haven't had time yet.
Public Function BankHolidays(lYear As Long) As Collection

    Dim colTemp As Collection
    Dim dDateInQuestion As Date
    Dim dTemp As Date
    Set colTemp = New Collection

    'New Years Day
    'If falls on a weekend then following Monday is BH.
    dDateInQuestion = DateSerial(lYear, 1, 1)
    If Weekday(dDateInQuestion, vbMonday) >= 6 Then
        dTemp = dDateInQuestion + 8 - Weekday(dDateInQuestion, vbMonday)
    Else
        dTemp = dDateInQuestion
    End If
    colTemp.Add dTemp, "NewYearsDay"

    'Easter
    'Easter is the Sunday so isn't added,
    'but Good Friday & Easter Monday are calculated from this date.
    dTemp = EasterDate(CInt(lYear))
    colTemp.Add dTemp - 2, "GoodFriday"
    colTemp.Add dTemp + 1, "EasterMonday"

    'Early May Bank Holiday.
    'First Monday in May.
    dDateInQuestion = DateSerial(lYear, 5, 1)
    If Weekday(dDateInQuestion, vbMonday) > 1 Then
        dTemp = dDateInQuestion + 8 - Weekday(dDateInQuestion, vbMonday)
    Else
        dTemp = dDateInQuestion
    End If
    colTemp.Add dTemp, "EarlyMayBankHoliday"

    'Spring Bank Holiday
    'Last Monday in May.
    dDateInQuestion = DateSerial(lYear, 6, 1)
    dTemp = dDateInQuestion - Weekday(dDateInQuestion, vbTuesday)
    colTemp.Add dTemp, "SpringBankHoliday"

    'Summer Bank Holiday
    dDateInQuestion = DateSerial(lYear, 9, 1)
    dTemp = dDateInQuestion - Weekday(dDateInQuestion, vbTuesday)
    colTemp.Add dTemp, "SummerBankHoliday"

    'Christmas Day
    'Records 25th as BH and following Monday if Christmas is on Saturday or
    'following Tuesday if Christmas is on Sunday.
    dDateInQuestion = DateSerial(lYear, 12, 25)
    If Weekday(dDateInQuestion, vbMonday) = 6 Then
        dTemp = dDateInQuestion + 8 - Weekday(dDateInQuestion, vbMonday)
        colTemp.Add dTemp, "ChristmasDay"
    ElseIf Weekday(dDateInQuestion, vbMonday) = 7 Then
        dTemp = dDateInQuestion + 8 - Weekday(dDateInQuestion, vbMonday) + 1
        colTemp.Add dTemp, "ChristmasDay"
    Else
        colTemp.Add dDateInQuestion, "ChristmasDay"
    End If

    'Boxing Day
    'Records 26th as BH.
    'If 26th is Saturday, then following Monday is BH.
    'If 26th is Sunday, then following Tuesday is BH.
    dDateInQuestion = DateSerial(lYear, 12, 26)
    If Weekday(dDateInQuestion, vbMonday) = 6 Then
        dTemp = dDateInQuestion + 8 - Weekday(dDateInQuestion, vbMonday)
        colTemp.Add dTemp, "BoxingDay"
    ElseIf Weekday(dDateInQuestion, vbMonday) = 7 Then
        dTemp = dDateInQuestion + 9 - Weekday(dDateInQuestion, vbMonday)
        colTemp.Add dTemp, "BoxingDay"
    Else
        colTemp.Add dDateInQuestion, "BoxingDay"
    End If

    Set BankHolidays = colTemp

End Function

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : EasterDate
' Author    : Chip Pearson
' Site      : http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Easter.aspx
' Purpose   : Calculates which date Easter Sunday is on.  Is good from 1900 to 2099.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function EasterDate(Yr As Integer) As Date
    Dim d As Integer
    d = (((255 - 11 * (Yr Mod 19)) - 21) Mod 30) + 21
    EasterDate = DateSerial(Yr, 3, 1) + d + (d > 48) + 6 - ((Yr + Yr \ 4 + _
            d + (d > 48) + 1) Mod 7)
End Function

Public Function NamedRangeExists(Book As Workbook, sName As String) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next

        NamedRangeExists = Book.Names(sName).Index <> (Err.Number = 0)

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Public Sub AllocateNamedRange(Book As Workbook, sName As String, sRefersTo As String, Optional ReferType = "R1C1")

    With Book
        If NamedRangeExists(Book, sName) Then .Names(sName).Delete
            If ReferType = "R1C1" Then
                .Names.Add Name:=sName, RefersToR1C1:=sRefersTo
        ElseIf ReferType = "A1" Then
                .Names.Add Name:=sName, RefersTo:=sRefersTo
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the thorough response. I will definitely have a look into incorporating this into my code.